# openfire server has no authentication in amazon cloud server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, xmpp, openfire

I am connecting to openfire using Smack api and it is connecting just fine. The problem is that anyone could connect to it if they know my ip address.It's not asking for admin password or anything and new users are created. Do I have to use some kind of certificate file (BKS or JKS)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could disable the Inband Account Registration setting Registration & Login page (under Server Settings tab) through your Openfire Admin Console.

Inband account registration allows users to create accounts on the server automatically using most clients.